# How to pass parameters to an exe through reflection?

Tags: vb.net, forms, reflection

This is my code (which works fine):

```
Private Sub open_report2()

    Dim oType As System.Type
    Dim oAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly
    Dim oObject As System.Object
    oAssembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\VB.NET\report3\report3\bin\Debug\report3.exe")
    oType = oAssembly.GetType("report3.r1")
    oObject = Activator.CreateInstance(oType)
    oObject.show()

End Sub
```

How do I pass a parameter to `report3`?

or

Can `report3` see variables in the calling program and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution so I wanted to post it here:

In my main program, I simply added one line:

```
oObject.show()
oObject.SetParams("a", "b")
```

Then in report3 I set it up like this...

```
Public Class r1

    Implements IPlugin

    Public a1 As String = ""
    Public b1 As String = ""
    ...
```

Then I set up a Subroutine inside of the r1 class like this:

```
Public Sub SetParams(c As String, d As String) Implements IPlugin.SetParams
        a1 = c
        b1 = d
        MessageBox.Show(a1)
End Sub
```

Then outside the class r1, I set up an interface like this:

```
Public Interface IPlugin
    Sub SetParams(ByVal c As String, ByVal d As String)
End Interface
```

And when I run my main program, I see the message box display "a" when I call open_report2.